# ServiceStack AutoQuery join use

Tags: ormlite-servicestack, autoquery-servicestack

After reading the documentation, I am not sure but I have come to the conclusion that when creating QueryDb, you cannot choose the columns to join by? And I am under the impression, you must have DTO object to copy to? You cannot copy to a regular object or a dynamic object?

`public class SampleAutoQueryDb : QueryDb<MailResponseDetailOrm, object>, ILeftJoin<MailResponseDetailOrm, MailResponseOrm> {   }`

Can anyone provide any insight on joining my MailResponseOrm to MailResponseDetailOrm. MailResponseDetailOrm has 5 fields namely the `Email` address. And I would like MailResponseOrm to be joined to it by `Email` as well. I also, for good measure do not want to alter either columnname. Would I have to create a custom implementation or a service to do this?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code as posted below:

```
        [Alias("MailReportsDetail")]
        public class MailResponseDetailOrm
        {
            public string Email { get; set; }

            public int ID { get; set; }

            [Alias("RespDate")]
            public DateTime? AddedDateTime { get; set; }

            [Alias("DLReport")]
            public string Action { get; set; }

            public string ActionDetail { get; set; }

            public string IP { get; set; }

            public string UserAgent { get; set; }

            public string EmailReferrer { get; set; }
        }

    [Alias("MailReports")]
    public class MailResponseOrm
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string Company { get; set; }

        public string Contact { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Alias("LastMail")]
        public DateTime? ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        [Alias("LastReport")]
        public string Action { get; set; }

        public DateTime? OptOut { get; set; }

        public string Part { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public string Source { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        #region Obsolete

        [Obsolete]
        public string Class { get; set; }

        [Obsolete]
        public string IP { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

public class SampleAutoQueryDb : QueryDb<MailResponseDetailOrm> { }

public class MyQueryServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    // Override with custom implementation
    public object Any(SampleAutoQueryDb query)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, base.Request);
        q.Join<MailResponseDetailOrm, MailResponseOrm>((x, y) => x.Email == y.Email)
            // .Select<MailResponseDetailOrm, MailResponseOrm>((x, y) => new { x.ID, y.Email })
            ;
        return AutoQuery.Execute(query, q);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins in AutoQuery needs to use [OrmLite's Joins Reference conventions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpression-support-for-joins) and all AutoQuery Services results are returned in a Typed DTO, which by default is the table being queried or you can use the `QueryDb<From,Into>` base class to return a [custom result of columns from multiple joined tables](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#returning-custom-results).

You would need to use a [Custom AutoQuery Implementation](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations) or your own Service implementation if you need customizations beyond this, e.g:

```
public class SampleAutoQueryDb : QueryDb<MailResponseDetailOrm> { }

public class MyQueryServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    // Override with custom implementation
    public object Any(SampleAutoQueryDb query)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, base.Request);
        q.Join<MailResponseDetailOrm,MailResponseOrm>((x, y) => x.Email == y.Email);
        return AutoQuery.Execute(query, q);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code but the lamdas are complaining that they are not in context. Why would that be?

Comment: So lol, I was close however. It still complains `x.Email= error CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context` and `y.Email= error CS0103: The name 'y' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @petrosmm Please update your question with the exact source code you’re using and the error. Note you cannot use object in your AutoQuery Request DTO, it needs to be a concrete POCO Type, with the table you want to query on and if you want to return custom results, a POCO with all the fields you want returned.

Comment: @petrosmm That code does not have any build errors.

Comment: apologies, it seems my build may have been cached because I just tried again and was successful. Seems like this question is in order and has been answered properly.

Answer (score 2):

// The query to join 2 objects on field names not specifically set in the class.

```
var q = Db.From<MailResponseDetailOrm>().Join<MailResponseDetailOrm>(x,y) => x.Email = y.Email);
```

// Run the query

```
var results = Db.Select(q);
```

Comment: Hi Bob, I was specifically asking about AutoQuery to be clear, unless I can re-use this in a service implementation.